# Flutter ElevatedButton onPressed function change

Tags: flutter, flutter-onpressed

I have a defined ElevatedButton, how to assign onPressed listener to another function?
something like this -

```
button1.onPressed() => log("something else");
```

```
 Widget button1 = ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () => log("something"),
    child: Text("name"),
  );
```

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
Widget getElevatedButton(Function funct) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () => funct(),
      child: Text("name"),
    );
  }
```

Then you will be able to pass whatever function you want to your ElevatedButton

```
var button1 = getElevatedButton(() => log("something"));
var button2 = getElevatedButton(() => log("something else"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Either recreate the button with the other function or in the function use `if-else` depending on a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You also go for it

```
getElevatedButton(funct: (){log("something else");});

Widget getElevatedButton({Function funct}) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: funct,
      child: Text("name"),
    );
  }
```